# Viewport border

Tags: html, css, border

I want to have an 8px solid black border around the viewport of the webpage.
It doesn't scroll, content scrolls from "behind" it. it's transparent.
If I use a fixed div with a large z-index, it will prevent interaction with elements under it.

How can I do this?
I can make 4 divs, one for each side with a width of 8px for right and left and height of 8px for top and bottom, but that's seems like a bad way of solving this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a great article on css-tricks.com about that issue: http://css-tricks.com/body-border/

The first one is the one with four divs, but others are somewhat better.

Comment: Broken link in your answer.  I believe this to be the replacement: (http://css-tricks.com/body-border)